# Deploying django with apache + mod-wsgi _ Error 500

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to deploy my first django app in windows 10 (x64), so installed apache 2.4(x86), installed and build mod_wsgi (4.9.1) with python 3.8(x86) (I have microsoft visual studio 2019 installed) and configured Apache httpd.conf and httpd-vhosts.conf files.
My app runs fine, but the annoying error 500 keeps showing every now and then, and goes away by refreshing the browser every time.

There seems to be a bug with python 3.8, so decided to upgrade to python 3.10 (X86),
Reinstalled mod-wsgi and other packages using pip in new virtual environment in the same directory, and reconfigured httpd.conf accordingly. now apache service fails to start with error: "windows could not start the Apache2.4 on local computer....".

If I change httpd.conf configuration to load and use the python3.8 , Apache starts with no error (but again Error 500 keeps showing).
by the way I tried the same with python3.9 (x64) and Apache 2.4 (X64), and apache fails to start again.

*Any help would be greatly appreciated.*

**In httpd.conf:**

*This configuration fails:*

LoadFile "C:/Program Files (x86)/Python310-32/python310.dll"
LoadModule wsgi_module "d:/django project/unemployment project/.venv/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp310-win32.pyd"
WSGIPythonHome "d:/django project/unemployment project/.venv"

*This configuration works:*

LoadFile "C:/Program Files (x86)/Python38-32/python38.dll"
LoadModule wsgi_module "d:/django project/unemployment project/venv/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp38-win32.pyd"
WSGIPythonHome "d:/django project/unemployment project/venv"

Comment: What do the server logs say, both the apache logs and Django's runtime? 500 errors (when you see the base error on a web page) are universal and pretty ambiguous, but in most instances I've seen it is an error with the code in the app somewhere, so I'd bet if you can see the logs from Django you'd find the answer to your issue.

Comment: The error was: "ValueError: set_wakeup_fd only works in main thread\r"

Comment: solution suggested in [link](https://github.com/django/asgiref/issues/143) worked fine.... by the way the solution was to add the line:     "WSGIScriptAlias / "\some\path\wsgi.py" application-group=%{GLOBAL}      to httpd-vhosts.conf file.